# Tkinter widget not visible until font set on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to do some tutorials on tkinter I had problems with making widget appear on created window. In examples I have found there were code for example for creating label as below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text='Hello world!')
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but widget do not appeared. Only by adding `myLabel.config(font=("Courier", 12))` I was able to make it visible.

My question is: is it problem of using tkinter on linux or problem with configuration of my dev environment ?

Comment: Are you certain it did not appear _at all_, or was the text simply invisible? Have you tried giving the label a distinctive background so that it can be distinguished from the window background?

Comment: I have tried for example background color and it shows as really small square, without text.

Comment: So, that probably means that your system is improperly configured to have a very tiny font as the default tkinter font. The widget is showing, but the font is very small.

Comment: To be precise I am using python 3.8.0 with tcl 8.6.8.

Comment: Could give some hint where to find this default setting ?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't worked on linux in several years.

Comment: I am using Archlinux and tkinter uses 'DejaVu Sans 9' as the default font  (you can check yours with `tkinter.font.Font().actual()`). 'DejaVu Sans' is the default system's font, though I am not sure about the size. So maybe you can try to change the default font on your system: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration, https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size (I have never tried).

Comment: Try to find what is the default tkinter font and then I think you should download the font onto your system. Cause if that does not already exist in linux then that might fix your issue.